# Dynamics CRM 2013: Unable to create campaign activity

Tags: dynamics-crm

I created a new organization in Dynamics CRM 2013 on premise, importing only a solution that was created by another team for a different purpose (have to use it for this customer).

I now want to create a campaign and add campaign activities to it. However, since importing said solution, I am unable to create campaign activities. I can't create them from the campaign overview nor from the campaign activites view. The litte plus or the "new" buttons are just not showing up.

Obviously the other team disabled this somehow with their solution, but I just cant figure out how they did it (neither do they..).
I checked the security roles, I have the Administrator role so should be able to do anything.

How else could you remove the ability to create campaign activities?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is these buttons are hidden in the ribbon explicitly. You can look at the hide actions in the ribbon XML.

Here's a tool to make ribbon editing easier:
http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/102796-5-hiding-unhiding-ribbon-elements

Here's an article that talks about using this tool to to show/hide buttons:
http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/102796-5-hiding-unhiding-ribbon-elements

Comment: unfortunately no, the buttons are not hidden. They are just not being displayed. Could this be an issue with rights?

Comment: @buddybubble, if you are a system admin, then rights can't be the issue. Is it on the subgrid of the campaign form that this is happening? Have you checked the enable and display rules on the buttons (using the same tool)?

Comment: Its happening both from the subgrid on the campaign form (the '+' is not displayed) and from the campaign activities form (accessed by the dropdown in the header ribbon of campaign). The campaign activities form even lacks the complete toolbar where the 'New' Button would normally be displayed. Again, I checked there are no custom .css or .js files in place

Comment: It sounds like a javascript loading error. Have you looked in the developer tools (F12) in your browser to see if any errors are showing up in the console?